# Android studio doesn't recognize MultiSelectListPreference in layout editor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to fill a MultiSelectListPreference with strings that would constantly change, the thing is no matter what example I take from online, my Android studio layout editor can't seem to recognize it as "MultiSelectListPreference" at all...

this is my xml object:

```
 <MultiSelectListPreference
    android:entries="@array/characterNames"
    android:entryValues="@array/characterNames"
    android:key="pref_characters"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:title="Chars :" />
```

and this is what Android studio thinks it is:

[image]

Comment: Does it show any errors?

Comment: you should not add multiseleclistpreference as child of "LinearLayout" .create new file preference.xml inside xml folder.for parent add <preferenceScreen> then add your multiSelecListPreference. refer here:                                                    https://alvinalexander.com/android/android-tutorial-preferencescreen-preferenceactivity-preferencefragment